# How can I import node module into svelte component

Tags: npm, import, module, typeerror, svelte

I'm new to svelte and I am trying to use an installed node module in my dependancies called momentum-slider. In the script tags of my svelte component I have:

```
import MomentumSlider from "../../node_modules/momentum-slider";
let slider = new MomentumSlider({
   el: ".ms-container",
});
```

In my component's html markup I have the suggested markup as shown in the tutorial at https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-fancy-countdown-timer-with-momentumsliderjs

However, I am getting a typeError in the browser console:

[image]

I am new to development in general and I am not sure if this is a problem with momentum-slider or an error on my part. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure how to use this library but you should take care of 2 things. First import your package like the following:

```js
import MomentumSlider from "momentum-slider";
```

Second you need to initialise the `MomentumSlider` class when the component is mounted using [onMount](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount):

```js
import { onMount } from "svelte";
import MomentumSlider from "momentum-slider";

let slider;

onMount(() => {
  slider = new MomentumSlider({ 
    el: ".ms-container"
  });
});
```

[image: Edit exciting-bouman-dyywc]

Comment: Many thanks @johannchopin! The corrections you suggested did the trick. I need to get my head around the lifecycle functions in svelte. I am thinking that **onMount** is like an eventlistener that listens to when the component has been inserted into the dom and **only then** runs the code inside. This would explain why the instance of MomentumSlider was failing to query the **.container** element as it did not yet exist in the html document. Is this line of thinking correct?

Comment: @stickleBrick Yep you give a correct explanation of your previous problem +1

Comment: So if it solves your problem please `validate` my answer :)

Comment: Apologies, I gave it a positive vote but was unaware of how to validate, I've done that now and it should have worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed the package properly: `npm install momentum-slider`
the package is listed in your `package.json`.

When this fits, you just have to import:
`import MomentumSlider from "momentum-slider";`

Comment: Many Thanks nologin for your suggestions. I have ammended the import statement as you suggested. momentum-slider is not listed in the package.json file but it is listed in the package-lock.json file. I'm not sure what the difference is between these two files but after following the advice of @johannchopin to use the **onMount** lifecycle hook I have been successful.

Comment: Fine that it is solved. The import is fixed as I recommended ;)
The "onMount" above takes care, that the DOM is already created.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, some packages use the `require` method in their documentation for usage in your work. Svelte doesn't really like `require` so a good alternative is

Instead of: `var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;`

Do this: `import { Validator } from "jsonschema";`